# Replace null values in a list with another value in Scala

Tags: list, scala, nullpointerexception, null

I'm attempting to replace the null elements of a Scala list with an empty value using `map`. I currently have:

```
val arr = Seq("A:B|C", "C:B|C", null)
val arr2 = arr.map(_.replaceAll(null, "") )
```

This gives me a NullPointerExpection. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: To truly understand the `map` function, I recommend http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to replace a null character in a string instead of replacing a null string in `Seq`. So here is a correct way:

```
val arr2 = arr.map(str => Option(str).getOrElse(""))
```

The `Option` here will produce `Some(<your string>)` if the value is not null and `None` otherwise. `getOrElse` will return your string if it's not null or empty string otherwise.

Comment: More idiomatic: `vs.mapConserve { case null => "" case x => x }`

Comment: Actually it's not recommended to use `null` in Scala directly.

Comment: The data in question already uses null. It's not forbidden to use the `null` keyword; you just want to limit it to a boundary like this one, when ingesting data. And to keep null out of API. They want Option to be a value class to avoid needless creating Option objects as you do here; in that case, your expr would be more appetizing.